# I want to open Msexcel inside my wpf application any one have any idea how to open inside wpf application

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

```
 void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\ss.prajapati\\Desktop\\Demo.xlsx";
            startInfo.Arguments = file;
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
```

I know how to open with process, Can any one give me example how to open excel inside My wpf application . I want to do like this [image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Out of interest why are you trying to do this? Will you want the file it creates later on for another process?

Comment: @Matt this is part of my project so i have to do this , user can directly edit throuth wpf application in excel sheet so it is good for my application

Comment: could you better explain what your trying to do with your project as a whole. Depending on your ultimate goal writing a plugin inside of excel, rather than a wrapper around the outside may be better. Regardless I have put a link below to point you in the right direction for your current question

Comment: @Matt I am working on document management system for one collage project they have all documents like word excel ppt and all kind of documents they have to perform all the operation from wpf application so i have to host ms office into the the wpf application

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/acbf043d-8381-4113-b8c4-572acf3c8711/open-exe-program-inside-wpf-window-possible?forum=wpf - you could use findwindow and setwindow to set the parent of excel to be your application